# How to change AR core project to AR foundation

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Hai I completed the AR Core project few months back but now I want application to works both in android and IOS so trying to switch the AR Core project to AR Foundation if anyone knows please help me out thanks in advance.

I try to Delete the AR Core cameras and update with AR session origin, AR session but still its not workout for me

Thank You.

Comment: Did you read [Getting Started With ARCore Extensions for Unity's AR Foundation](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity-arf) and then probably [Enable ARCore functionality in your Unity projects](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity-arf/enable-arcore) ?